# JavaScript date object from <input type=date>

Tags: javascript, html, date, object, input

I'm trying to create a javascript date object in the focus.add_days function to add some days to the given date in a  element.
the problem is that the javascript object doesn't expect a string "Y-m-d" so how can I create the date object without parsing the string "Y-m-d" into pieces, or is the only way?

```
trigger = {
fecha_ini: function(){
    $('input[name="fecha_ini"]').on('change',function(){
      console.log('hi');
      var fecha_fin = $(':input [name=fecha_fin]');
      var min = $(this).val();
      //here is where i pass the "Y-m-d" string as the date argument
      var max = fechas.add_days(min,31*4);
      fecha_fin.attr('min',min);
      fecha_fin.attr('max',max);
      fecha_fin.val('');
    })
  }
};

fechas = {
  add_days: function addDays(date, days) {
    //here is where i use the string "Y-m-d" to create the date object, but obviusly doesnt work
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
};

trigger.fecha_ini();
```

Comment: have a look at moment.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> how can I create the date object without parsing the string "Y-m-d" into pieces, or is the only way?

While *Date.parse* will convert strings in y/m/d/ format to date objects, manual parsing is the only sensible way:

```
// s is format y-m-d
// Returns a date object for 00:00:00 local time
// on the specified date
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
}
```

ES5 specifies a [form of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) that should be supported by all browsers, however it is not supported consistently or by all browsers in use.

Comment: thanks, so as i tought i will have to split the text, i just wanted to know if there was a better aproach to the problem.

Comment: I can't believe this is the correct answer.  Why HTML5?!

Comment: @cgatian—[*"HTML5" is a buzword*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#is-this-html5?), it's just HTML. ;-) An ISO 8601 format date parsed by the built–in Date constructor will be treated as UTC, so users west of Greenwich see dates for the day before. But HTML wants them treated as "local"… go figure.

Answer (score 29):

Use [`valueAsDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

> `valueAsDate`
>   Returns: `Date`
>   Returns / Sets the value of the element, interpreted as a date, or `null` if conversion is not possible.

**Demo:**

```html
<input type="date" id="d" value="2018-02-14">

<button onclick="console.log( document.getElementById('d').valueAsDate )">
change the date (or not) and click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

## UTC

javascript `Date` object parses the raw value of `<input type=date>` in the UTC time zone, always!

```js
new Date(input.value) // Date object, date interpreted as UTC but printed in the local TZ
Date.parse(input.value) // Unix time in ms, date interpreted as UTC
```

## Local Time Zone

If the value of the `<input type=date>` is meant to be interpreted in the **local timezone**, then you can force it by adding a time like this:

```js
new Date(input.value+"T00:00") // Date object, date interpreted and printed in the local TZ
Date.parse(input.value+"T00:00") // Unix time in ms, date interpreted as local TZ
```

## Why?

*emphasis mine*

> For example, "`2011-10-10`" (date-only form), "`2011-10-10T14:48:00`" (date-time form), or "`2011-10-10T14:48:00.000+09:00`" (date-time form with milliseconds and time zone) can be passed and will be parsed. **When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description

Answer (score 3):

With me it's working without doing anything.

I just write
   new Date($('#html5dateinput').val());

that's about it. I get the correct date object. I'm using Google Chrome ver 38 and I tested it on Firefox 33 under Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This has very inconsistent results. at the time tested on Chrome and `new Date("2017-10-19")` gives off the correct date in GMT while `new Date("2017-10-9")` gives the date in my own timezone.

Answer (score 2):

**[Use valueAsNumber](https://jsfiddle.net/rck9q6hh/1/).**

```
var myDate = new Date(input.valueAsNumber);
```