# Date comparison is not working in jQuery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-comparison

The alert is showing every change event, but the `if` condition is not working. How to fix it?

Here is my code.

```
$("input").change(function() {
  var date = document.getElementById('<%= txtRegisteredDate.ClientID%>').value;
  var todaydates = new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy');

  if (date > todaydates) {
    alert('date is greater than today date');
  }
})
```

Comment: There is no `format` function in Date

Comment: Even if `.format` worked. Why are you comparing _strings_ in a `dd/MM/yyyy` format? If you wanted to compare strings, you’d use `yyyy-mm-dd`. But you can just compare `Date` objects directly: `new Date() < someOtherDate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: You might want to look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641525/javascript-date-object-from-input-type-date

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your date variables to an object before the comparison.

e.g:

```
var date = document.getElementById('<%= txtRegisteredDate.ClientID%>').value;
var todaydates = new Date();

if((new Date(date) > todaydates))
{
   alert('date is greater than today date');
}
```

Comment: Please accept as answer if this has solved your issue :)