# Changing 'new Date' to input value

Tags: javascript, date, timer, countdown

I'm new to coding so please go easy on me..

I'm creating base apps so I can get some experience with JavaScript, one of them is a countdown timer involving an input that you input a date/time into and the idea is to initiate a countdown from getTime - inputTime.

I've tried implementing a 'change' event listener to change the textContent.

```js
var timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
var timeCounter = document.getElementById("timeCounter");
var deadline = new Date('dec 31, 2020 15:37:25').getTime();
// var deadline = document.getElementsById("timeInput").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var t = deadline - now;
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("timeCounter").innerHTML = days + "d " +
    hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (t < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timeCounter").innerHTML = "EXPIRED" + " Enter a new date.";
  }
}, 1000);

timeInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  timeCounter.textContent = t.textContent;
})
```

The page counts down from 428days regardless of changing the date input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your change handler, set `deadline` to the `getTime()` value of a new `DateTime` object based on the `timeInput` value:

(e.g. paste `2019-12-31 18:00:00` into the input and remove the focus from it, and the countdown should start at 57 days)

```js
var timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
var timeCounter = document.getElementById("timeCounter");
var deadline = new Date('dec 31, ' + (new Date().getFullYear()) + ' 23:59:59').getTime();
// var deadline = document.getElementsById("timeInput").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var t = deadline - now;
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  timeCounter.innerHTML = days + "d " +
    hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (t < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    timeCounter.innerHTML = "EXPIRED" + "Enter a new date.";
  }
}, 1000);

timeInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  deadline = new Date(timeInput.value).getTime();
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="timeInput" />
<div id="timeCounter"></div>
```

The issue with your code was that `deadline` was never updated, and also the variable `t` is a local variable, only available in the callback function you passed to `setInterval`.

You can further do some optimization. As you already have the `timeCounter` reference, you don't have to use `document.getElementById("timeCounter")` om your callback function, just use the reference instead.

Comment: re `new Date(timeInput.value)`, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Good point! This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641525/javascript-date-object-from-input-type-date/23641753#23641753 Using a library like `momentjs` might also be an alternative to handling date/time related issues.

Comment: Moment (or any parser) can only reliably parse a string if the format is known. If the format is known, then a simple parser is only a few lines of code. So importing a large library simply to parse a single format is somewhat extravagant.

Comment: How we can set the timezone?

Comment: @ShankarSBavan You can add a specific time zone like this: 2021-07-31 18:00:00 +02:00